# I want to change the image of a image button simultaneously onClick event

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

In the below code i tried to change the image on first click(working). But on second click it should change back to original state. Likewise it should change on every click simultaneously. Please explain me the logic. i am new to android. Thanks in advance

```
ib_accordion1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ib_accordion1);
ib_accordion1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ib_accordion1.setImageResource(R.drawable.minus_icon);  
        }                                       
 });
```

Comment: You can set a **boolean* `true` on FirstClick and `false` on second click.

Comment: Thnaks it worked for me.

Comment: May be u can upVote the comment alteast ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a simple boolean value to determine it's state.

```
boolean isOriginal = true;

ib_accordion1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ib_accordion1);
                ib_accordion1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                        isOriginal = !isOriginal;
                        ib_accordion1.setImageResource(isOriginal ? R.drawable.original : R.drawable.minus_icon);                                          
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean original = true;    

img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            original = !original;
            img.setBackgroundResource(original ? R.drawable.ic_action_new_light
                    : R.drawable.ic_action_chat_light);
        }
    });
```

Actually, I have edited above comment and worked for me thanks to Sai Chakradhar Sana.